# Открывание проекта с другой компоненты

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, rxjs

Как по умолчанию при запуске проекта делать вывод не localhost:3000 а выбранную компоненту, к примеру localhost:3000/sign - чтоб такая компонента запускалось при открывании проекта

Comment: вам нужен роутер и там настроить базовый роут

Answer (score 0):

`.\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts` тута смотри файлы, в них открытие

Но, я бы:

- Либо компоненту в app перенес, т.е. `localhost:3000/sign` в `localhost:3000`
- Либо со стороны браузера совершал переход..

Энивей, хз зачем так, ибо `yarn\npm start` будет обновлять страницу на которой ты находишься, если все правильно сделал